# Let a, b, c, d be odd integers(CLOSED)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

Let $a, b, c, d$ be odd integers where $0 \lt a \lt b \lt c \lt d$. It is known that $ad=bc$ while $a+d$ and $b+c$ are powers of $2$, i.e., there exist positive integers $x,y$ such that $a+d=2^x$ and $b+c=2^y$. Show that $a=1$

I have tried replacing d=$\frac{bc}{a}$ etc., but it does not work.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Inorder to find the numbers (a,b,c,d) you'll need to provide four(4) different set of information

Comment: This question was in the 1984 IMO https://www.imo-official.org/year_info.aspx?year=1984

Answer (score 1):

I expect there is a more elegant solution to this, but at least this works (barring arithmetic error which, of course, is always possible):

First remark that we must have $a+d>b+c$:

Pf:  Indeed $$c(b-a)=bc-ac=ad-ac=a(d-c)<c(d-c)\implies c(b-a)<c(d-c)\implies $$$$\implies (b-a)<(d-c)\implies 
 (b+c)<(a+d)$$ as desired.

It follows that $x>y$.

Now write $d=2^x-a$ and $c=2^y-b$ to deduce that $$ad=bc\implies 2^xa-a^2=2^yb-b^2\implies 2^y(b-2^{x-y}a)=(b+a)(b-a)$$

Since $a,b$ are both odd we must have that $2^{y-1}$ divides one of $b+a$ and $b-a$ (since $\gcd (b+a,b-a)$ divides $2b$ and $b$ is odd).

Case I:  $2^{y-1}\,|\,(b-a)$ .  This is absurd since it would imply that $b>2^{y-1}$ which would imply that $c>2^{y-1}$ and then $b+c>2^{y}$ which is false.

Case II:  $2^{y-1}\,|\,(b+a)$  So $(b+a)=2^{y-1}n$.  If $n≥2$ then we'd have $(b+a)≥(c+a)$ which is false so we must have $n=1$.  Hence $$b+a=2^{y-1}$$

Finally we can put all this together:

$$a=2^{y-1}-b\quad \&\quad c=2^y-b\implies c=2^{y-1}+a$$  Hence $$bc=ad\implies (2^{y-1}-a)(2^{y-1}+a)=a(2^x-a)\implies 2^{2y-2}-a^2=2^xa-a^2\implies $$ $$\implies 2^{2y-2}=2^xa$$
which, finally, implies that $a=1$.

Comment: Very small typo, I think the last equation in third to last line should be $c =  2^{y-1} + a$.

Comment: @erdoswiles  Absolutely correct, thanks for catching it.  And thanks for checking the rest of it...it's all elementary but there are a lot of steps and errors are hard to trap.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinite results that can fix into your equation, infant is a Diophantine equation

$(a,b,c,d)    €       odd integers$

Where $0<a<b<c<d$ and $a*d = b*c$ and $a+d = 2^x$ and $b+c = 2^y$, where $(x,y) € Z$

The set of odd integers include

$(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,......)$

If we imagine that $a=1$, just to create the smallest solutions to the problem

Since $a+d = 2^x$
They'll be grouped in this way

$[ (1,3),(1,7),(1,15),(1,31),(1,63),..... ]$

Since $a*d = b*c$, their product must be equal to the product of two other odd numbers, therefore will exclude the prime therein

Then the first set of solutions for $a$ and $d$ are $:$

$[ (1,15),(1,63),(1,255),(1,1023),....... ]$

By the splitting of this numbers, we create the values of $b$ and $c$, because $15=3×5$, $63=7×9$, $255=15×17$,     $1023=33×31$

Then the simplest-case solutions are

$(1,3,5,15)$

$(1,7,9,63)$

$(1,15,17,255)$

$(1,31,33,1023)$
e.t.c

Now let's imagine $a$ was not $1$, say $a=3$ (the next odd number)

So the list of the sets that combines to make $a+d = 2^x$ are

$[ (3,5),(3,13),(3,29),(3,61),(3,125),...... ]$

Since $a*d = b*c$, their product must equal to the product of two other smaller odd numbers, remember that $0<a<b<c<d$, so we'll exclude the primes 
Therefore the solutions for $a$ and $d$ here are

$[ (3,125),(3,253),(3,2045),........... ]$

By splitting up this numbers, when create the values for $b$ and $c$

Because $125=5*25$,    $253=11×23$,                $2045=5×409$,........

A problem then occurs it wouldn't satisfy that $b+c = 2^y$

> This results are wrong
>   $(3,15,25,125)$
>   $(3,5,75,125)$
>   $(3,23,33,253)$
>   $(3,11,69,253)$
>   $(3,5,1227,2045)$
>   etc

So maybe the only value of $a$ that works is when it's equal to $1$

Proofing it takes a different kind of maths